# My Birthday PuzZle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Today is a special day for me. I somehow managed to achieve the quite symmetrical age of 33. But wait, it is also my 3rd birthday celebrating here with you. Coincidence? Noooo, it's a pattern!

This year, I prepared a special Puzzle for you. Roll your sleeves, unpack your curiosity, polish your associative and deductive skills, wake up your experimental spirit. Real detectives are wanted!

To get you on the on the right way, search for hidden clues also here in my post. Follow the signs and unlock their meaning. But don’t get confused by the direction. At the end, as in all good detective stories, there is of course, just one question: Who is the Murderer?

The game is on!

[image]

Comment: Does it have to do with the full title / artist of the book/song/film these seem to reference? IE, Electric Avenue by Eddy Grant, with the 58 meaning the 5th and 8th letters of 'Eddy Grant', or GN? I read the left/right as directional for those letters, and ended up with: _ _ _ S I N G O _ T _ H R E E, because I can't identify a few. Could be way off base here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of the generous clue by Epicedioin, who really deserves the credit, the murderer is...

> The wedding photographer, Jonathan Small aka the Mayfly Man.

I got that from the decoded phrase...

> The Sign of Three

The connection is...

> The Sign of Three is an episode of the show Sherlock. In that episode, the photographer is the killer.

Each street name refers to a band, movie, or tv show.

They are from top to bottom:

> The Doors, The Simpsons, Eddy Grant, Harry Potter, Fight Club, The Beatles, A Nightmare on Elm Street, Green Day

Use the numbers to find specific letters in each title. For example, the "123" in Sign 1 leads to the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd letter of "The Doors," which is "The." Put together to form

> The Sign of Three

Comment: well done :) excellent

Comment: Thanks! The lion's share of the credit goes to @Epicedion

Great puzzle!

Comment: Don't forget that the connection is clued with the last line of text!